# Handling NULL values in Spark StringIndexer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, categorical-data, apache-spark-ml

I have a dataset with some categorical string columns and I want to represent them in double type. I used StringIndexer for this convertion and It works but when I tried it in another dataset that has NULL values it gave `java.lang.NullPointerException` error and did not work.

For better understanding here is my code:

```
for(col <- cols){
    out_name = col ++ "_"
    var indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol(col).setOutputCol(out_name)
    var indexed = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
    df = (indexed.withColumn(col, indexed(out_name))).drop(out_name)
}
```

So how can I solve this NULL data problem with StringIndexer?

Or is there any better solution for converting string typed categorical data with NULL values to double?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.2**

Since Spark 2.2 `NULL` values can be handled with standard [`handleInvalid`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer@handleInvalid:org.apache.spark.ml.param.Param[String]) `Param`:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer

val df = Seq((0, "foo"), (1, "bar"), (2, null)).toDF("id", "label")
val indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("label")
```

By default (`error`) it will throw an exception:

```
indexer.fit(df).transform(df).show
```

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$9: (string) => double)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1066)
...
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: StringIndexer encountered NULL value. To handle or skip NULLS, try setting StringIndexer.handleInvalid.
  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel$$anonfun$9.apply(StringIndexer.scala:251)
...
```

but configured to `skip`

```
indexer.setHandleInvalid("skip").fit(df).transform(df).show
```

```
+---+-----+---------------------------+
| id|label|strIdx_46a78166054c__output|
+---+-----+---------------------------+
|  0|    a|                        0.0|
|  1|    b|                        1.0|
+---+-----+---------------------------+
```

or to `keep`

```
indexer.setHandleInvalid("keep").fit(df).transform(df).show
```

```
+---+-----+---------------------------+
| id|label|strIdx_46a78166054c__output|
+---+-----+---------------------------+
|  0|    a|                        0.0|
|  1|    b|                        1.0|
|  3| null|                        2.0|
+---+-----+---------------------------+
```

**Spark < 2.2**

As for now (Spark 1.6.1) this problem hasn't been resolved but there is an opened JIRA ([SPARK-11569](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11569)). Unfortunately it is not easy to find an acceptable behavior. SQL NULL represents a missing / unknown value so any indexing is kind of meaningless.

Probably the best thing you can do is to use [`NA` actions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions) and either drop:

```
df.na.drop("column_to_be_indexed" :: Nil)
```

or fill:

```
df2.na.fill("__HEREBE_DRAGONS__", "column_to_be_indexed" :: Nil)
```

before you use indexer.